# How to develop OSGi software and deploy in different implementations?

Tags: java, osgi, modular-design

I am starting develop modular apps with OSGi framework. My first concern is if I can develop using felix dependencies in my source code then later run my code in Concierge.

I looked for Concierge examples over the Internet, but there is no a good tutorial with examples at least I did not find out something good, please if you know something let me know.

So, my question is simply if I can develop using specifications and run everywhere in terms of platforms (Concierge, Felix, and others).

Thanks in advance for your support on it,

Regards,

-Rod

Comment: In general yes. This is the great thing about OSGi being a standard, and one that is very well specified. Implementations such as Equinox, Felix, Concierge etc comply with that standard so you can easily write software that works on all of them. You just need to take care about the version of the specifications that you use compared to the version supported by the specific framework implementation you choose.

Answer (score 1):

The OSGi specifications are split into three parts:

- Core: These specifications are normally implemented by the OSGi framework. I am not sure if every framework supports all specs but until now I did not spot any that were not supported. So typically these are always available.
- Compendium, Enterprise: These specifications are normally supported by specific bundles. So you have to make sure to install a bundle that implements the spec you want to use. For example you can install felix config admin if you want to use the configuration admin spec. Normally you can mix these like use equinox framework but still install felix config admin.